# Event on middle click pie chart slice?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to get a middle click event for the Highcharts pie chart api, but I can't find anything in their [api documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart) for it.

I created this test to demonstrate that there's no `console.log` when you middle click a slice, but there is a `console.log` when you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>, or regular <kbd>click</kbd> it.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            console.log('clicked on y: ' + this.y);
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: [{
                y: 29.9
            }, {
                y: 71.5
            }, {
                y: 106.4
            }]        
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Is there any way to fire an event when I middle click a pie chart slice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other then default events given by highchart like `click`, you can also attach events on the container. In you case it can be `mousedown` event.

[Attach event to container](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-container/)

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',                
            }
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: [{
                y: 29.9
            }, {
                y: 71.5
            }, {
                y: 106.4
            }]        
        }]
    });
});

$(document).on('mousedown', '#container path', function (e) {
    if(e.which==2)
     console.log('Middle click on slice '+e.target.point.x+ " value is "+e.target.point.y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: updated the answer. We can bind event only for the graph then.

Comment: I think this is probably closer to what is desired: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/6po5h4yb/1/. Where you can get series/point infromation on clicking.

Comment: Thanks @ewolden, that works nicely! Still, I'd hoped there'd be an api way of doing it. It's a good workaround though :)